# Wifi fails when switching OS on dual boot PC

Tags: linux, windows, wireless-networking, multi-boot

I have a dual boot system currently with Ubuntu and Windows. Over the last couple of months, I had a repeated experience of failing WiFi card when switching between operating systems. The wifi (and other wireless connections) seem to be in some kind of failed state (not showing up in linux at all as if my PC didn't support wireless connections; windows sometimes shows erorrs such as "Device can not start (Code 10)", other times doesn't show up either).

It does not happen everytime and I am not sure what are the exact conditions. It seems to happen most often when I restart the system in Ubuntu and boot into Windows immediately. When this happens, the Windows loading screen always loads a for lot longer time. After the wifi fails, rebooting into any OS doesn't help.

What always solves the issue is turning the computer off and unplugging it completely for at least a minute. After that, the wifi works just fine in both operating systems.

While this does solve the issue when it inevitably happens, it is a frustrating experience and I would like to know the underlying cause. I am not sure whether this is a hardware issue or where to look for errors.

I have used different linux distro on the same PC in the past and I had the same issues. I have also tried other troubleshooting steps such as reinstalling drivers, restarting the wifi device in Windows device manager with no luck. Could you please point me in the right direction?

Comment: Are you shutting Windows down fully before booting into Ubuntu? Have you considering using a Virtual Machine for one of your OSes so you're only actually booting the computer with one OS? What are the system specs and details?

Comment: What do you mean by shutting Windows down fully? As I said in my question, this usually happens when I restart the computer i.e. shut 1 OS down fully and boot into the other OS. I don't want to use a Virtual Machine, I am happy with dual boot which I think is appropriate for my use case. Relevant systems specs: ASUS B550M-PLUS WIFI II motherboard, AMD Ryzen 7 5800X CPU, 32 GB RAM, Windows 10, Ubuntu 23.10.

Comment: Is Fast Startup enabled on your computer? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/477733/is-it-necessary-to-disable-fast-boot-in-windows-to-dual-boot-with-linuxefistub

Comment: No, Fast Boot is disabled.

Comment: "Fast Boot" is a firmware (UEFI) feature; "Fast Startup is a Windows feature (the link confuses it but you mustn't). You should try disabling the later.

Comment: This: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/643300/191360

Comment: Fast Startup is disabled in Windows as well. Is there something similar in Linux?

Comment: No, there isn't and it's irrelevant. You should REALLY check if it's actually disabled as many Windows feature updates tend to re-enable it.

Comment: I double checked it and it is definitelly disabled. Most people are reporting issues when rebooting from Windows to Linux while having Windows Fast Startup enabled. I am having the exact opposite problem, it usually happens when rebooting from Linux to Windwos. I think this is somehow caused by some setting in Linux that causes the wifi card to not be properly switched off or something. A feature similar to "Windows Fast Startup" inside linux might explain this behaviour.

Comment: I would but there isn't such feature therefore it isn't it. You may have to shutdown instead of rebooting.

Comment: how do you connect to the internet? does it also happen if you try another way to get internet?

Comment: I connect with wifi. Other ways (ethernet, usb tethering) work fine.

Comment: I mean things like the router (have you access to configure?), the provider (some restrictions?), dhcp (release the ip, stop dhcp and restart to another os). Another way = another wifi network. Is the computer name the same in both systems?